# Visual Studio 2013 Coded UI Remote Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have created a simple test in coded UI (open up the trash can). I then setup test settings with remote execution and selected my test controller which is connected to 2 agents. I then run the the test in test explorer and it runs the test but only against one agent. Is there any way I can get it to run against both agents simultaneously or even one after the other?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What on earth are you on about?

Comment: In Visual Studio I have created a simple coded ui test. This test simply launches the Recycle Bin.  I have installed a test controller which is connected to 2 test agents.  This connection all works fine.  When I launch a distributed test using the test controller it runs that test against one of the agents and not the other.  I am trying to get it to launch one test against multiple Agents.  Basically i'm trying to test against multiple OS by having an Agent installed on each OS and connecting to one controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting in the test settings file, but not something that's adjustable within the Visual Studio IDE.  Specifically, you'll need to open the file in a text editor and adjust the value for the `MinimumTestsPerAgent` property.  There's some good information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a658fc38-080f-461d-9373-12ef4ce6e1e7/limit-on-concurrent-test-agent-runs?forum=vsunittest) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/10/17/10048788.aspx).

Comment: Thank-you for the links, The MinimumTestsPerAgent was the key.  From what I've read in the comments though you basically still need to create separate test runs for each test to get it to work.  I basically created the same test twice and it ran the test on both of my agents at the same time.  I think I can work with this to get a setup which will push a set of tests to each remote machine.  Not the optimal solution but it should work without needing to use MTM.  Thx again